# Code to display articles from category ID?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

What would be the code to display articles from category (specified by ID)?

In Wordpress this is fairly easy by doing:

```
<?php
   query_posts('cat=1');
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   the_title();
   endwhile;
?>
```

I'm looking for similar code for Joomla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct code for getting this in joomla like word press.

If you want to check the code you can check the code for achieving this by following path.

```
components/com_content/view/category/view.html.php

and 
components/com_content/view/category/tmpl/blog.php
```

According to my Guess your requirement is to display the articles from same category.

then in joomla you dont need to edit in any code.
for achieving this you can simply create a menu.
and menu layout type should be category blog and Choose your category from the right side category options.

This will get the complete article from that category.

If you want to manage it in your style you can add style based on blog.php file .

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 12):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$id = 50;//example

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('#__content');
$query->where('catid="'.$id.'"');

$db->setQuery((string)$query);
$res = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($res as $r){
    echo '<h3>'.$r->title.'</h3>';
    echo $r->introtext;
}
```

Comment: Superb answer. Just wanted it.

Comment: can i get custom fields with this db query too ? they dont appear in my object :/

Answer (score 6):

You can use next code template:

```
$categoryId = $[category id];

require_once("components/com_content/models/category.php");
$category = new ContentModelCategory();
$category->hit($categoryId);
$articles = $category->getItems();
print_r($articles);
```

Comment: Consider adding a summary of how this code works to flesh out your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$articles = JFactory::getDBO()->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid = '21'")->loadObjectList();
```

Of course replace '21' with id of your category.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy in Joomla. You can find the code in */components/com_content/models/category.php* under *getItems()*

Below is an example

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$model->setState('params', JFactory::getApplication()->getParams());
$model->setState('filter.category_id', $category_id);

$articles = $model->getItems();
```